# How can I set one directional relation between two fields (in same table or different) in Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using CodeFirst for my devemopment. For all model classes in my Entity I have  a base class named CommonFields

```
public class CommonFields
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int CreaedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And, for eg. I have two classes like

```
public class Employee : CommonFields
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

public class User : CommonFields
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}
```

How can I set relation from CreatedBy & ModifiedBy to User table. I just need only one directional mapping.

I need to get User information when I write objEmployee.CreatedUser

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CommonFields
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedById { get; set; }
}
```

and you have to define relations for all derived entities in your DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<User>().HasOptional(x => x.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    mb.Entity<User>().HasOptional(x => x.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ModifiedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    mb.Entity<Employee>().HasOptional(x => x.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    mb.Entity<Employee>().HasOptional(x => x.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ModifiedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Or you could use TPH. Then your model creating look like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<CommonFields>().
            .Map(x => x.ToTable("Users"))
            .Map<User>(x => x.Requires("__type").HasValue(1)
            .Map<Employee>(x => x.Requires("__type").HasValue(2);

    mb.Entity<CommonFields>().HasOptional(x => x.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    mb.Entity<CommonFields>().HasOptional(x => x.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ModifiedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```